# Does RHEL 8.3 support MATLAB Compiler Runtime Version 9.0?

Tags: matlab, rhel

I've been using MATLAB R2016a (9.0) in Windows 10 and MATLAB Compiler Runtime Version 9.0 in RHEL 7.2. I used to compile the code in Windows & run the binaries on the target machine (50GB RAM, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 0 @ 2.30GHz, 12 cores) having RHEL 7.2. Now the OS is upgraded to RHEL 8.3 in the target machine. Without even knowing whether the MATLAB Compiler Runtime Version 9.0 is supported in RHEL 8.3 or not, I took the binaries & ran them on RHEL 8.3 and observed that the performance (processing speed wise) has degraded. Earlier the binaries used to take X amount of time. Now it's taking X+Y amount of time.
Generally, the OS upgrade must improve/retain the performance instead of degrading it. So please clarify my doubts mentioned below,

1. Is MATLAB Compiler Runtime Version 9.0 supported in RHEL 8.3?
2. If supported, what could cause the performance degradation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I presume the former can be found in the documentations for the MATLAB Compiler, the latter we can't answer without seeing your code.

Comment: Adriaan, Thanks for the reply. Official documentation (https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/SystemRequirements-Release2016a_Linux.pdf)  says, the supported OSs are "Red Hat Enterprise
Linux 6 and 7". But it doesn't mention clearly whether it's RHEL 6 & 7 onwards or RHEL 6 & 7 Only.

Comment: Initially the MATLAB Code was written with MATLAB 7 and the same code has been consistently performing good over the MATLAB releases 8 & 9 over RHEL 5, 6, 7. The slowness was observed only when we migrated to RHEL 8.3. So i'm not finding any reason to suspect the MATLAB code. Please share some pointers if i'm missing.

Comment: "Earlier the binaries used to take X amount of time. Now it's taking X+Y amount of time." This adds literally 0 amount of information to your post. Earlier statements already made clear it's taking more time. If you could at least give some indication of the magnitudes of X and Y,  then it'd be helpful. But still, telling you why something is slower on your upgraded OS is impossible without knowing more about the program and the system. Is it I/O that caused the slowdown? Is it basic matrix algebra? Is it memory constraints? Did you re-install the MCR?